# html execute javascript function when requested not on page loading

Tags: javascript, html, function, bootstrap-modal

I have a javascript function and I want to execute it at a certain point into a bootstrap modal

The script should be for example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saluto(){
    window.alert('Ciao');
}
</script>
```

The modal 'modifica' is called in this way

```
<td>
    <a href="#modifica<?php echo $id;?>" data-toggle="modal">
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true' title="Modifica"></span></button>
    </a>
    <a href="#cancella<?php echo $id;?>" data-toggle="modal">
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true' title="Cancella"></span></button>
    </a>
</td>
```

Inside the modal, there is HTML code to do something. At a certain point, I want to execute the function 'saluto'. I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript"> saluto(); </script>
```

but the message don't appear

Comment: You can have an event handler for the button click and then use the `setTimeout( )` function for delayed execution for the content inside the callback function.

Comment: When do you want to run `saluto()`? is it in response of clicking on something?

Comment: When I press the button modifica (modify) a modal opens. There I have 'n' checkboxes, some checked and some not. My javascript let me to modify a 1/0 string depending if I check or uncheck checkboxes. In the example the script simply launch a messagebox. The script must start only when the checkbox state change